# Vue3 - How to enable/disable text input and checkbox based on input number

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

```
<div class="container-body" v-for="index in 10" :key="index">
    <div class="container-content"></div> 
    <div class="container-content">
        <input :id="'Row'+index+'-input1'" type="text">
    </div> 
    <div class="container-content">
        <input :id="'Row'+index+'-input2'" type="text" class="disabled">
    </div> 
    <div class="container-content">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input :id="'Row'+index+'checkbox'" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" disabled>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="container-content delete">
        <img/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I will have 10 input rows using v-for.

I need to achieve:
When user enter number on Row1-input1, Row1-input2 and Row1-checkbox will be enabled. The input enabling should not affect the other 9 rows. Also, when I click on the delete div, it should clear the whole row value.

I'm not sure how to achieve this in Vue. Should I create 10 data variables, and save the value onkeyup, and use it bind with :disabled ? Or are there any Vue methods that can achieve this ?

Comment: Add ```v-model``` or ```:value``` and make bind ```:disabled```. It also make you easy to clear the inputs.

Comment: @Newbee How does v-model work for multiple rows ?

Comment: You only need a ```unique``` value. You already do it here ```:id="'Row'+index+'-input2'"```

Comment: @Newbee means that i need to create 10 variables, and bind it to the 10 rows right ?

Comment: No since you already have a **loop**. I can't say the full detail in this comment so I will post an answer. If it doesn't suit you, please do inform me so I can delete it. If that's the answer you are looking for, make it as good answer or just voting up is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

here is an approach:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container-body" v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="index">
      <div class="container-content"></div>
      <div class="container-content">
        <input :id="'Row'+index+'-input1'" type="text" @input="enableRow(index)" v-model="row.input1">
      </div>
      <div class="container-content">
        <input :id="'Row'+index+'-input2'" type="text" class="disabled" :disabled="!row.input1">
      </div>
      <div class="container-content">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input :id="'Row'+index+'checkbox'" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" :disabled="!row.input1" v-model="row.checkbox">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-content delete" @click="clearRow(index)">
        <img />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      rows: Array(10).fill({
        input1: '',
        input2: '',
        checkbox: false
      })
    };
  },
  methods: {
    enableRow(index) {
      if (this.rows[index].input1) {
        this.rows[index].input2 = '';
        this.rows[index].checkbox = false;
      }
    },
    clearRow(index) {
      this.rows[index].input1 = '';
      this.rows[index].input2 = '';
      this.rows[index].checkbox = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this method, when i enter a number at the input1 , then the whole array input1 became the number

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to create a component for one line, where you can put all the logic for working with one instance. And then create the required number of such components.

Here is an example implementation for your task, if I understood everything correctly:

```js
const {
  computed,
  createApp,
  ref,
} = Vue;

const defaultRowValue = {
  input1: '',
  input2: '',
  checkbox: false
}

const customRow = {
  props: ['index', 'modelValue'],
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  setup(props, {
    emit
  }) {

    const model = computed({
      get: () => props.modelValue,
      set: (val) => {
        emit('update:modelValue', val)
      }
    })

    const disable = computed(() => model.value.input1);

    const clearRow = () => {
      model.value = { ...defaultRowValue
      };
    }

    return {
      model,
      clearRow,
      disable,
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div class="container-body">
      <div class="container-content"></div>
      <div class="container-content">
        <input :id="'Row'+index+'-model.input1'" type="text" v-model="model.input1">
      </div>
      <div class="container-content">
        <input :id="'Row'+index+'-model.input2'" type="text" v-model="model.input2" class="disabled" :disabled="!disable">
      </div>
      <div class="container-content">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input :id="'Row'+index+'checkbox'" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" :disabled="!disable" v-model="model.checkbox">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-content delete">
        <button @click="clearRow">delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
}

const app = createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      rows: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {

    // Create test data
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      this.rows.push({ ...defaultRowValue
      })
    }
  }
})

app.component("custom-row", customRow);

app.mount('#app');
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <custom-row v-for="(_, key) in rows" :key="key" :index="key" v-model="rows[key]"></custom-row>
  </div>
  <pre>
    {{rows}}
    </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the **uniqueness** of your input(s).

As I said before, you can make a `:value` or `v-model` of your input.

Then concatenate the each a string and index to make an unique input.

In doing so, You need to return a v-model of input with an `array` type **NOT** a `string` type.

This is because, we need to make a concatenation with string and an index.

So we can do like this v-model

**For input 1**

```
v-model="row.input[index+'-input1']"
```

**For input 2**

```
v-model="row.input[index+'-input2']"
```

So we can now have an access to our row inputs.

And we can use it with the `disabled` and `delete` function.

[Demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)